# Is there vendor specific event for exiting the "select scroller" interface in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, dom

I have an issue where when a user taps on a `<select>` box it opens the "scroll wheel" interface in iOS which pushes the modal they are interacting with up. This is fine, but it doesnt then restore the modal's position when the interface closes.

Are there any vendor specific DOMEvents or css pseudo-elements i could use to invoke a position calculation and change when this ui element is closed (either through the "done" button or by tapping outside the interface)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar, though not identical issue with the iOS scrolling select widget. In my case, the page would zoom when the scrolling select widget opened, and did not zoom back out when it was closed.

Oddly the fix was to set the font-size relatively large:

```
/* iPhone4+ select box fix */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    select { font-size: 2em; }
}
```

The media query ensured this only took place on an iPhone.

Comment: -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2 will also trigger on, say, a Retina Macbook Pro, not just on an iPhone.

Comment: @JesseRusak Thanks for that -- I should mention that I also reset the `select` box `font-size` in subsequent media queries for desktop layouts.